# How to see the value of a parameter inside a With-Block while debugging?

Tags: vba, debugging, visual-studio-2019, resharper, with-statement

When debugging in a Visual Basic Project in Visual Studio 2019, I can't see the values of parameters inside a With-Block when I'm hovering over it with the mouse.

I have Resharper Ultimate installed, but it seems like it doesn't provide a function to show it either.

When using a With-Block the values of ".Name", ".URL", etc.
aren't shown when hovering over them in debug mode:

```
Private Sub AddCustomer()
    Dim theCustomer As New Customer

    With theCustomer
        .Name = "Coho Vineyard"
        .URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
        .City = "Redmond"
    End With

    With theCustomer.Comments
        .Add("First comment.")
        .Add("Second comment.")
    End With
End Sub
```

---

When it is this way, the debugger shows the values just as usual:

```
Private Sub AddCustomer()
    Dim theCustomer As New Customer

    theCustomer.Name = "Coho Vineyard"
    theCustomer.URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
    theCustomer.City = "Redmond"

    theCustomer.Comments.Add("First comment.")
    theCustomer.Comments.Add("Second comment.")
End Sub
```

How can I see the values? Or is there a way to convert the With-Blocks automatically to regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

[image]

Are you sure that you are talking about VB6? Resharper Ultimate sounds more like an extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I'm working in Visual Studio, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: And you are right, that it doesn't work in Visual Studio. You will have to use a Watch window or query the value in the immediate window. I think there is next to no chance that Microsoft will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see the values of parameters inside a With-Block when I'm
>   hovering over it with the mouse.

Do you use [DataTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-data-values-in-data-tips-in-the-code-editor?view=vs-2019)?

I test it in VS2019 16.1(Community and Professional Edition). In a VB.net console app using your example code, we can use DataTips to monitor variable value in debug mode.

Hover over the `thecustomer` variable and we can get its details during debugging.If this option not work in your side, try repairing VS or update it to latest VS version.

[image]

Hope it helps:)